# Asynchronous helper functions

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm having trouble figuring out how to structure a helper function that can be used as part of a conditional when that helper function is asynchronous.

I've defined two Parse Cloud Code functions that check if a user has a valid account and respond in slightly different ways, so I figured I'd create a third helper function that simply checks if a user has a valid account. This is what the three functions look like:

```
// Check if user account is active before allowing saves.
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Item", function(request, response) {
  if (isActiveUser(request.user)) {
    resonse.success();
  }
  else {
    response.error("Inactive user");
  }
});

// Checks if calling user account is active.
Parse.Cloud.define("isActive", function(request, response) {
  if (isActiveUser(request.user)) {
    response.success(true);
  }
  else {
    response.success(false);
  }
});

// Returns true if user is active.
function isActiveUser(user) {
  var query = new Parse.Query(User);
  query.first({
    success: function(user) {
      if (user !== null && typeof user === 'object') {
        return true;
      }
      else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

The intent of the isActiveUser function is to return true or false, but as Jaromanda points out, it doesn't return anything at all. I'm not sure how to structure this in a more event-driven manner that will actually work. I'm hoping someone can help this inveterate PHP programmer trying to break into JS :)

Comment: `isActiveUser` doesn't return anything at all - so, equivalent to `return undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using callback in your function - "isActiveUser()"

Rewrite as :

```
function isActiveUser(user, callback) {
  var query = new Parse.Query(User);
  query.first({
    success: function(user) {
      if (user !== null && typeof user === 'object') {
        callback(" Active ",true);
      }
      else {
        callback(" Non-Active ",false);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

And call this function :

```
...
isActiveUser( your_user_item , function(err,flag){
  if(flag == true){
      // This User is active
  }
  else{
      // Non active , show some msg
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that inner functions could inherit variables from outer functions (i.e. that the `response` object would be available inside the callbacks). But it seems like that should work.

Comment: Haha , I think they were in the same scope.